# How can I use class from another jar in JAVA?

Tags: java, manifest.mf

I have a little app that uses

```
import simple.http.Request;
import simple.http.Response;
import simple.http.load.BasicService;
import simple.http.serve.Context;
...
```

When running the jar file (`java -jar test2.jar`) I receive this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: simple/http/serve/ResourceEngine
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    ...
```

Google-ing I have found that that class (simple.http.serve.ResourceEngine) is part of [simple-2.7.jar](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/simpleframework/simple/2.7/simple-2.7.jar!/simple/http/serve/FileEngine.class?classDetails=ok).

I have modified MANIFEST.MF file like this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_17-b02 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: com.App.Main
Class-Path: simple-2.7.jar
```

downloaded `simple-2.7.jar` and copied near my jar file the but the error persist

I an NB in java. Can you help with info how to make the jar work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the java program by using this command instead

java -jar test2.jar -cp simple-2.7.jar

Hope simple-2.7.jar is in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

You have to add simple-2.7.jar to your classpath.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html